# Which ERD is more correct re proper Database Design?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, erd

Which ERD is more correct re proper Database Design?

### ERD #1

[image: ERD 1]

or

### ERD #2

[image: ERD 2]

Please explain why one is more correct than the other.

- ERD 1 Author: [Ben Grunfeld](http://github.com/bengrunfeld)
- ERD 2 Author: [Darren Frenkel](http://github.com/darrenfrenkel)

Comment: This topic is rather subjective because it really depends on what level of normalization a database needs or how much normalization developer(s) are comfortable with or knowledgeable about implementing.  If you and Darren are simply posting this up to show who is right and wrong, you've picked the wrong place to hash this out.

Comment: @SlyRaskal, We're trying to learn about good Database Design practices. I thought that was the general idea of StackOverflow, and apologize if I was mistaken.

Comment: No worries, just giving you a heads up about the focus of this site.  While there is *much* you can learn from this site.  This site's primary focus is give the community a well explained and support problem, and you will get an answer on how to fix it.  There are topics, like this one, that in my opinion doesn't fit that mold because it could lead to more subjective opinions being shared than objective opinions.  Just my two cents. I would read this quick page to give you an idea of what is appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  Cheers.

Comment: Also just wanted to add that your response to josephtikva1's answer should have been a comment to their post, not a separate answer.  That is a no-no on the site,  You may want to copy and paste it as a comment under josephtikva1's post and delete that answer so that you don't get dinged for it. ;)  Same goes for your other item that was posted as an answer, unless you intended your response to serve as the *actual* answer to Ben's posted question.

Comment: This would probably fit http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion **ERD #1** is a better design.

**Reasons**

> Orders/Product Table will have OrderID for a particular Order and for each Product Orderd and
>   quantity for that product for each Order. no repetition/No redundant data.

**ERD #2**

> Is a poor design as each order can have multiple products and you will
>   be adding the same orderid, CustomerID, Invoicedetails for multiple
>   products for the same Order, in simple words more redundant data.

**Edit**

> ERD #2 also violates the database normalization rules. In orders Table
>   you have InvoiceID and then Invoice_Creation_Date which only depends
>   on the InvoiceID .
>
> normalization rules say if a column in a table doesnt directly depend
>   on the Primary Key in that column it should be in a separate table. In
>   other words all the columns in a table should Directly depends on
>   Primary key only.

Answer (score 0):

1. In ERD 1 you can only have one item per order -- hence the need for a join table in ERD2
2. ERD2 - Why would you have a FK in the invoice table for order_ID, and also have invoice_ID in the order table. One FK field is enough. I assume this is a one order to many invoices, in which case you would put the order_ID in the invoice table

Comment: In ERD 1, in the ORDER/PRODUCTS table, you can have as many order items as you like, as they receive the PK `order_product_ID_PK`, so I believe that your first point is incorrect.

Comment: @BenGrunfeld: I think he (accidently?) swapped ERD1 and ERD2 in #1

Answer (score 0):

ERD2 is written incorrectly the foreign key Order_ID_FK should be removed from Invoices. Therefore, Invoices should have a one to many relationship with Orders.